# Reputation not recording in ACHIEVEMENTS dropdown, only in the reputation tab

Tags: bug, reputation-history

One of the downvotes is not being recorded from under the "ACHIEVEMENTS" dropdown, only in the "reputation" tab and have noticed this within the past hour.

This isn't a caching issue on my computer, since this is happening on two different machines.

Is this is a bug or an actual "system-wide" caching issue?

I've taken a few screenshots.

**Edit:** I downvoted another answer (just a few minutes ago from my editing this) which I felt did not address a question and that recorded the vote in the dropdown and the one I addressed originally is still not showing. **See screenshot #4.**

**1)**
[image]

**2)**
[image]

**3)**

[image]

**4)**

[image]

Comment: Try again?  If it were caching it would have cleared itself up within an hour.

Comment: @Makoto I've done this and as I said in the question, this is on more than one machine.

Comment: @Makoto I've made an edit to the question. About screenshot #4 and next to **Edit** . That is most bizarre.