# Achievement notifications are no longer updating in real time

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-history, achievements-dialog

Is there an issue with the notifications of achievements? I noticed that it has not been updating for 2 hours now.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, the data is not synchronized with the reputation tab. Has anyone faced the same issue or is it only me?

Comment: I appear to be seeing this too, yes. Last notification was for a silver badge I earned, and +15 accept and +10 vote (once the new UTC day arrived and the daily rep cap was reset) have not been shown in the achievements box.

Comment: Your thinly veiled excuse to show off +696 points earned today isn't fooling us.    Congratulations anyway!  ;-)

Comment: This seems to affect only rep though, I just got a "Good Answer" badge notification, without the one upvote that did trigger it in the Notification Box.

Comment: I also have not seen any updated in the rep inbox today, though everything else seems OK.  And yes, getting nearly 700 points in one day is just obscene.

Comment: It's not just you; I haven't had anything unusual happen today (like a large bounty), but my rep box dropdown hasn't been updating.  My rep for today is still below the 200 cap.

Comment: Duplicate of [Reputation not recording in ACHIEVEMENTS dropdown, only in the reputation tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/350202), but presumably that bug from last year had a different cause.  (And there were no answers or explanation about what happened last time.)

Comment: I concur, got +11 score and nice answer for [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51719866/918959) that I answered an hour ago - the badge shows in the dropdown but nothing else does.

Comment: This issue on Meta.SE: [Reputation on SuperUser not appearing in Rep. Notification Queue - yet it is given silently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313701/289905).

Comment: @kjhughes well it wasn't my intention and honestly I thought it's probably a bug related to a high reputation earned in one day that's why I shared the screen :) .. And I confirm also that I got the *good answer* badge for this question and still no rep changes.

Comment: Not sure if it is related but my StackExchange app on Android "user activity" tab is also stuck at yesterday... Might be a strange coincidence.

Comment: Confirmed here too, but interestingly badges *are* showing up, it's just rep that isn't

Comment: I wish I got a quater of that reputation every day

Comment: I'm also missing notifications for at least 2 upvotes and an accept today.

Comment: I'm working on a fix for event aggregation now. We have about 2 million in queue and it'll take a few minutes to drain once resolved.

Comment: This is reoccurring on at least a few sites.

Comment: @Rob I guess it's due to the recalculation stuff across all the network

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Our aggregation queue got jammed up with a bad item here (and we'd rather stall that discard data since it's terribly expensive to analyze and fill gaps after the fact). The bad entry has been handled (data wider than the column in 1 path) and we're now draining. Since we were at 2.25 million items it'll take 10-20 minutes or so to drain out.

Once that happens, everything should be back in place.

Comment: They are coming now one by one.

Comment: Do you want to add answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313701/reputation-on-superuser-not-appearing-in-rep-notification-queue-yet-it-is-giv) too?

Comment: The problem occurs again.

Comment: Hi Nick, is there an issue with this queue at this moment? notification are't getting on the top.