# Not getting notification of reputation or achievements

Tags: bug, reputation-history, achievements-dialog

I think there an issue with the notifications of achievements?

Today I have received 3 upvotes

Check the screenshot

[image]

But not received notifications of achievements

[image]

Has anyone faced this issue?

I'm using FF 61.0.1 (64-bit) & Version 64.0.3282.119 (Official Build) (64-bit)

**NOTE** I have already check this [Achievement notifications are no longer updating in real time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372100/achievement-notifications-are-no-longer-updating-in-real-time)

Comment: [Seems a network-wide issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315836/reputation-changes-not-visible-in-the-achievement-box) and [the devs are on their way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315836/reputation-changes-not-visible-in-the-achievement-box#comment1035001_315836)

Comment: Seems to be fixed now

Comment: yes it seems fixed, I got all the notification/reputation at the same time now

Comment: Notifications have been completely buggy for as long as I've been using SO. In particular, it has always showed the wrong number of new messages on the inbox icon, often counting messages I have already read. This bug goes back long before the new top bar.