# Achievement & message notifications aren't updating in real time

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-history, achievements-dialog

Like I reported [previously](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/372100/8620333) my notification aren't updating correctly. I didn't get notified for all the votes I got. The inbox message is also doing the same. I received a message late and probably there is some messages I didn't receive.

Is it only me or there is a bug somewhere?

**Update**

They are getting back again but still missing the old ones.

Comment: Related: [Top bar notifications (global inbox, +reputation) don't really clear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327309/289905).

Comment: @SebastianSimon not really the same issue but probably linked to the same bug.

Comment: Pretty certain that's the same issue, because this all goes through Redis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We [effectively had a Redis outage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/327313) earlier today, but things should be back to normal now.